# CORS Pre-flight error when contacting self-hosted WebApi service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cors, preflight

I got this error when the Web portal contacts an self-hosted WebAPI service located in other server than the Web portal server:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'someportaldomain' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

The self-hosted service always return "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in every response, but if the browser decides to do a pre-flight before calling the url, the user gets this error on the js console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post the answer here, since i didn't find any straight on and had to pull it out from several posts.

The Solution is to add Options method to the Self-hosted service, like this:

```
[ServiceContract]    
public interface IACT_HttpService
{
    //[FaultContract(typeof(ValidationFault))]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "OPTIONS", UriTemplate = "*")]
    void GetOptions();

  //My other methods
  ...
}


public class ACT_HttpService : IACT_HttpService
{
    //Adjust this method to restrict the origin as needed
    public void GetOptions()
    {
        log.Debug("Get options fired");
        //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        //Add here any special header you have
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type");
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-A}llow-Origin", "*");            

        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
```